# Upgrade to Windows Server 2008 R2 - licensing issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have a license for Windows Server 2008 Enterprise which I got it from the Heroes Happen Here 2008 event that I have installed on a box at my home. I use that box for .Net development. Can I upgrade to Windows Server 2008 R2 with that license or am I stuck with the pre R2 version. If I can upgrade where can I get the DVD image for R2 to download for the upgrade.

I want to use the new Dublin hosting environment that is available as an IIS extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server 2008 R2 is a separate product, not an update to Server 2008 and so needs a new licence, you cannot use your existing server 2008 licence.
Personally I think the R2 naming is a little confusing, as it seems it should just be an update, but its not.